# How to keep checkbox checked when page refresh JavaScript, Spring Boot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, checkbox

I am working on an ecommerce web app using Spring Boot. So there are multiple checkboxes for product filter according to various options like Price, Discount, Size, etc.
Below is my JavaScript function to update the product listing page when the category checkbox is checked.

```
function updatelisting(cid){
  debugger
  var checkboxid = 'checkbox'+cid;
  var c = [];
  $('[id="'+checkboxid+'"]').each(function(i,e){
    if($(e).is(':checked')){
      c.push(e.value);
    }
  })  
  var category = c.join();
  var url = "api/searchbyfilter";
  $.post(url,{
    category : category,
  }, function(data, status) {
    if (data.status == "OK") {
      if (data.statusCode == 1) {
          var list = data.response;
          if(list.length > 0){
            for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
              window.location.href = "shopitems?type="+list[i].product.category.categoryid+"";
              selecttab(<%=pagelength%>);
            }
          }else{
            alert("No product found");
          } 
        } else {
          var error = data.responseMessage;
        swal(error, "", "error");
      }
    } else {
      var error = data.responseMessage;
        swal(error, "", "error");
      }
  });
}
```

**How to keep checkbox checked after page refresh or reload? How to write query parameters when passing multiple values in URL. Please suggest a solution.**

Comment: Maybe use localstorage instead? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: You have to store the checkbox state, either on the server or in the browser in sessionStorage or localStorage. It depends on your exact use case.

Comment: Do you have any example?

Answer (score -1):

You can save your checkboxes states (all filters) in URL as you mentioned. In ecommerce projects using this solution because you can share the link with others and you should save your selected filters

```
example.com?checkbox1=value&checkbox2=value&...
```